# Prove or disprove that there exists no more specific match-ups involving these 4 third-placed teams for the round of 16 other than

Tags: graph-theory, generating-functions, bipartite-graphs, algorithmic-game-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

UEFA EURO 2020 has been just started, still with the format of 24 teams. The top 2 in each groups will proceed to the round of 16 along with the best of 4/6 third-placed finishers. Prove or disprove that there exists no more specific match-ups involving these 4 third-placed teams for the round of 16 other than
$$\begin{matrix} \mathsf{1B}\vee \mathsf{3A}/\mathsf{D}/\mathsf{E}/\mathsf{F} & \mathsf{1C}\vee \mathsf{3D}/\mathsf{E}/\mathsf{F}\\ \mathsf{1F}\vee \mathsf{3A}/\mathsf{B}/\mathsf{C} & \mathsf{1E}\vee \mathsf{3A}/\mathsf{B}/\mathsf{C}/\mathsf{D} \end{matrix}$$
FYI, here are the combinations of matches in the round of 16_ [in.format](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFA_Euro_2020_knockout_phase),
is it related to a *generating function* for all the possible scenarios ? Can you give me a hint ? Thanks a real lot !
**Edit (07/11/21)**. I will describe my plan by qubit. I should start with the much easier-to-understood problem:
**Hall's Marriage**. Given two pairs of men and women whom participate in a couple's show. Realize that Mrs. $\mathsf{A}$ fancies Mr. $\mathsf{C}$ and Mr. $\mathsf{D},$ on the other hand, Mrs. $\mathsf{B}$ only fancies Mr. $\mathsf{D}.$ The best move here is $\mathsf{A}$ chooses $\mathsf{C}$ and $\mathsf{B}$ chooses $\mathsf{D}.$ Well, this is the Mathematics behind:
If $\mathsf{A}$ doesn't care the thinking of $\mathsf{B}$ then $\mathsf{A}$ has more than a possible way, I call it the state $11.$ And $\mathsf{B}$ who has only a possible way, I call it the state $01.$ Assume that $\mathsf{A}$ is full-of-selfish, that means $11\rightarrow 01.$ If $\mathsf{A}$ chooses $\mathsf{D}$ and $\mathsf{B}$ chooses $\mathsf{C},$ who knows ? This is the situation that $\mathsf{B}$ can't forsee, that means $01\rightarrow 10.$ So $10$ is satisfied here, huh ? No. In the logic law, $1\Rightarrow 1, 0\Rightarrow 1, 0\Rightarrow 0$ are true but only $1\Rightarrow 0$ is false, I call the states on purpose (I work with the decimal $\mathsf{base-}10$ and the binary "$\mathsf{base-}10$" too, very frequently). In conclusion, $11\oplus 01\rightarrow\mathsf{unknown},$ maybe $10$ or $01.$ I solve the problem by making $01\rightarrow 00,$ totally true by the logic law, $\mathsf{true}\Rightarrow\mathsf{true}.$ That leads to $11\oplus 01\rightarrow 11\oplus 00\rightarrow 11.$ This is my big picture about that
$$\begin{matrix}\mathsf{pairs} & A & B\\ C & & \times\\ D & & \end{matrix}$$
$$\begin{matrix}\mathsf{pairs} & A & B\\ C & & \times\\ D & & \checkmark\end{matrix}$$
$$\begin{matrix}\mathsf{pairs} & A & B\\ C & & \times\\ D & \times & \checkmark\end{matrix}$$
In the beginning, we should limit the choice of $\mathsf{A}$ with only $\mathsf{C},$ that's all.
**Combinations of matches.** Okay. Let's describe them on the big picture
$$\begin{matrix}\mathsf{match-ups} & B & C & E & F\\ A & & \times & & \\ B & \times & \times & & \\ C & \times & \times & & \\ D & & & & \times\\ E & & & \times & \times\\ F & & & \times & \times\end{matrix}$$
There are $14$ positions in the state $11.$ And observing that every rows and every columns has more than $2$ choices, if we make two of rows full, no problem, we always has a possible sequence of choices. Without loss of generality, we consider with only the columns $\mathsf{E}$ and $\mathsf{F}$ permitting the rows $\mathsf{A}$ and $\mathsf{B},$ that's the hardest case
$$\begin{matrix}\mathsf{match-ups} & E & F\\ C & & \\ D & & \times\end{matrix}$$
It's already on the top. I think $14$ is also the best constant here. That makes the most suitable states $01$ and $11.$ What's your thinking ? Just let me know.

Comment: I find this question incomprehensible.  What does $1{\rm B}\vee 3{\rm A/D/E/F}$ mean?   What is "not such as equal numbers of men and women in_ Hall's marriage theorem alluded to" supposed to mean?  Please try to restate it as an English sentence.  Also, please explain how the matchups for the round of $16$ are determined, and how the competition works.

Comment: If you really want an answer, please invest more time in asking the question. What is a match-up, what do you consider more specific? Certainly what is written lacks determinism: if both the teams ranked 3 in groups E and F proceed, the will play in the matches of the top row, but it is unclear which one will play which match.

Comment: There is a table titled "Combinations of matches in the round of 16" in the linked wikipedia page.  What exactly is your question that is not already answered by that table?  E.g. according to the table, 1B-3A implies 1E-3B.  Is this the "more specific" match-up that you're looking for?

Comment: In other words, does your question ask whether it is possible to make a table that allows to predict the matchups more precisely? That is, with less uncertainties?

Comment: Did you mean to start the bounty for “rewarding an existing answer” instead? If not,could you elaborate what needs updating specifically?

Comment: @Saad copy that, sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this answers fully your concerns, but it may help. The table below, which is taken directly from [the UEFA regulation](https://documents.uefa.com/v/u/WVKcnryVkASzztwJjPBcIw), paragraph 21.05, shows the different options for the round of 16 pairings,
depending on which third-placed teams qualify from the final tournament group
matches.

Depending on the quadruple of 3rd-ranked teams (left column), the second column shows which teams will be matched against $1B,1C,1E,1F$ respectively.

$$\begin{matrix}
A & B & C & D & | & 3A & 3D & 3B & 3C\\
A & B & C & E & | & 3A & 3E & 3B & 3C\\
A & B & C & F & | & 3A & 3F & 3B & 3C\\
A & B & D & E & | &3D & 3E & 3A & 3B\\
A & B & D & F & | & 3D & 3F & 3A & 3B\\
A & B & E & F & | & 3E & 3F & 3B & 3A\\
A & C & D & E & | & 3E & 3D & 3C & 3A\\
A & C & D & F & | & 3F & 3D & 3C & 3A\\
A & C & E & F & | & 3E & 3F & 3C & 3A\\
A & D & E & F & | & 3E & 3F & 3D & 3A\\
B & C & D & E & | & 3E & 3D & 3B & 3C\\
B & C & D & F & | & 3F & 3D & 3C & 3B\\
B & C & E & F & | & 3F & 3E & 3C & 3B\\
B & D & E & F & | & 3F & 3E & 3D & 3B\\
C & D & E & F & | & 3F & 3E & 3D & 3C\\
\end{matrix}$$

Note that this table is more specific than the one in the question. Indeed, if $3A,3B,3C,3D$ qualify, the original table was allowing also the option  $ 3A - 3D - 3C - 3B$ in the first row. So, this is a proof that it was not describing the future matching uniquely.

Instead, the table that describes all possibilities trivially determines uniquely the matchups.